# PHP array_push() is pushing object incorrectly into another array before pushing

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass, array-push

I'm looping over some data and dynamically creating an object which I want to push into an array.

```
$messageObj = new stdClass(); $recipientsObj = new stdClass();
$messageObj->message_recipients = Array();

$size = count($results);
for( $j = 0; $j < $size; $j++ ) {
    $recipientsObj->recipient_name = $results[$j]['recipient_name'];
    $recipientsObj->phone_number = $results[$j]['phone_number'];

    var_dump(json_encode($recipientsObj)); // DUMP 1

    array_push($messageObj->message_recipients, clone $recipientsObj);

    var_dump($messageObj->message_recipients); // DUMP 2
}
```

**PROBLEM**

`// DUMP 1` outputs the expected data - for instance

`string(55) "{"recipient_name":"JOHN DOE","phone_number":"123456789"}"`

But when I push the object into the array, the object is pushed as an array so I get:

```
[ [{...}], [{...}], [{...}] ]  // DUMP 2
```

instead of

```
[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

What could be causing this? Am I pushing it the wrong way?

Comment: Hi Clint, I'm not seeing that behaviour: https://3v4l.org/YN073

Comment: And it may be better to take `$recipientsObj = new stdClass();` inside the loop (as local var in the loop scope

Comment: @Nick you're right - I just tracked down the bug to another section of the code where I'm doing an `array_chunk` that led to the issue in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Tracked down the bug to a section of the code where I was performing an `array_chunk` on `message_recipients` and pushing the chunk to an array (`$messageObj->message_recipients`) leading to the issue in the question.

So I simply resolved it by equating `$messageObj->message_recipients` to the chunk instead of `array_push()` since it is already an array.